# I am trying to figure out how to make my confirm dialog box pop up when i hit the send button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to figure out how to make my confirm dialog box pop up when i hit the send button. Ive tried many different ways i just cant seem to make it work.code so far

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Confirm");
builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Do nothing but close the dialog

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // Do nothing
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();



public void send(View v) {



    new Send().execute();


}
```

Comment: What is wrong with it? what is the error?

Comment: the dialog pops up before i hit the send button

Comment: so put it inside the click of button !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setTitle("Confirm");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");

    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Do nothing but close the dialog
           new Send().execute();
           dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            // Do nothing
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

The most important thing is: you can create the instance of the dialog anywhere but you should put alert.show(); inside the method send(),

Comment: Why is the send button still executing while the dialog box is showing.

Comment: Because it is asynchronous

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Let me recap the story. So you want to show a dialog, then when users click on the "YES" button, the send button will be executed?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: It works thank you sooooooo much...you are a big help

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `alert.show()` method **inside onclick**.

change your code as

```
public void send(View v) {

     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setTitle("Confirm");
     builder.setMessage("Are you sure?");
     builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         new Send().execute();
         dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });
     builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        }
     });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
 }
```

And in your xml file, add this line for the send button.

```
android:onClick="send"
```

Comment: Why is the send button still executing while the dialog box is showing.

Comment: still executing while the dialog box is showing--> what do you mean. Do your action in positive button onclick. I have edited my answer

Comment: Happy to help you :)